# Youtube v3 API, videoCategoryId ignored if relatedToVideoId specified

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to list videos related to a certain video with category filter like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?fields=items,nextPageToken&key=<api_key>&maxResults=5&part=snippet&relatedToVideoId=_z9SeoQllUE&type=video&videoCategoryId=10
```

However, the category filter is ignored when I use relatedToVideoId.

Is this a bug, or just undocumented?

Thanks
Yaron

Comment: Filed: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7640

Answer (score -1):

The parameter ***videoCategoryId*** is of String type and the value you have provided in the REST API call is "`10`". This is not a valid value hence it is ignored.

According to the official documentation "The videoCategoryId parameter filters video search results based on their category". And if you take a look at the [Video Category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories) documentation "**A videoCategory resource identifies a category that has been or could be associated with uploaded videos."**

Comment: That's not right. The param should be filled with the category ID ('10') not the name. I've tried all options so I know. Also, the filtering is working perfectly w/o the related video thing. Just adding the related makes it stop working.